# Simple CLI rss reader, that can print only subject and uri, based on new since time interval

Tags: command-line, software-rec, rss-aggregator

So what I'm looking for is easy enough to code, but I'm wondering if it already exists, so I don't going releasing duplicate code.

I need a feed reader, that prints the subject, and uri on one line, to stdout. It should be able to be configured (not necessarily by config file) to only show new feeds in say the last 5 minutes.

The reason I want this is because I'm coding my [ping.fm](http://ping.fm) replacement. I basically want to be able to do something like `feedreader | pingit` where `pingit` will do, `foreach` line of input, make a separate post. In this way I'll also be able to `echo -n "my social post" | pingit` I'll probably also make `pingit "post"` work.

Answer (score 7):

Look into [`rsstail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/rsstail/), especially `-oil` options

Comment: voteup - thanks for letting me know about rsstail :)

Comment: -o doesn't seem to work in 1.6 it's not even in the output of the wrong syntax help. though it is oddly in the man page.

Answer (score 0):

In a side conversation [mst](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/) recommended [perlanet](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perlanet/bin/perlanet) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I created this python script where you can add rss feed urls and depending on how often you run it, it will print the links of the rss items for each feed that are new since the last run/update of the command:

https://github.com/ikwyl6/rss-checker